# Testing in python a part of a class method

Tags: python, django, database, testing, synchronization

I'm working with Python 3.x and Django 2.0.
I have a class which has the goal of starting a synchronization between two DBs. It has a method for the synch, and this method is composed of different parts:

1. Send an HTTP Request to the other server (it tries to send the request for a certain amount of attempts, then it stops);
2. Check the result (response received or number attempts exceeded);
3. Check the Response (Status code, format, response content (It's a JSON), ...)

After that, it starts again doing this, while there's nothing to synchronize.

Now, I need to test these different parts separately, but I don't know how because, as I said, these OPS are all in the same method.

I thought of a solution that would be separate these operation in different "sub" methods (only for testing purpose) or execute those parts of code in different tests. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Yes, a good first step would be to separate out the parts that have distinct functionality into their own methods. Then you should be able to test those methods separately.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll do this. However, i'm new to practical testing, as i said. So, can you also give me some advices for the future? I don't know, such as designing code in "sub" method as in this case or designing first the tests and then starting programming... Every advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Since you are using Django, you should do a search for unit testing in Django.